# How can I profile disk space consumers in a neo4j store?

Tags: memory, profiling, neo4j

When considering disk space used by a neo4j store, it is possible to roughly separate data between what is needed by Lucene (the content of the index folder) and what is used by neo4j itself (the content of my neo4j folder).

But, like in [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) as an example, is it possible to profile, at both edges and vertices level, which elements/subgraphs are the biggest disk space consumers ?

Comment: It is not built in, but one can do that, e.g. using the batch-inserter and going over the store files (nodes, rels) and aggregating that data.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Do you mean nobody ever had need for checking what elements of a neo4j store uses the most space ?